# Error with position dodge in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm currently facing an error using ggplot2. I want to create a barplot with standard error bar using this data frame :

```
       mean        se       pattern quality
1 54.955357 19.792315        spread    good
2 54.506944 18.580981       clumped    good
3 29.604167 14.937291 centered good    good
5 23.300595 14.336305        spread     bad
6  8.371528  5.960366       clumped     bad
7 16.364583 11.525207 centered good     bad
8  7.062500 11.125915  centered bad     bad
```

I use this formula to create my bar plot :

```
ggplot(table, aes(x=pattern, y=mean, fill=quality))+
geom_bar(position="dodge")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se, 
                  width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.9)))
```

But when I run it, the window that should have my barplot appears blank and this error message pops up

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type proto/environment. Defaulting to continuous
Error : Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:position_dodge(0.9)
```

When I try to run it without `position=position_dodge(0.9)` a bar plot appears but the bars are between each bar of means and not in the middle.

I've tried several value for `dodge` and other things but i'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Try having `position=position_dodge(0.9)` outside the `aes` specification in the last line.

Comment: since `width` isn't being changed by a variable, you should put it outside the `aes` specification as well

Comment: Great ! It worked, well kind of. An other error as occured ("ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric"), i'm looking for a solution but hopefully everything will go fine after.
Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

I got a warning that "stat_identity" (mapping to value, not count) was applied. To prevent that warning, simply add `stat="identity"` to the geom.

```
te <- c("val mean se pattern quality", 
    "1 54.955357 19.792315 spread good", 
    "2 54.506944 18.580981 clumped good",
    "3 29.604167 14.937291 centered_good good",
    "5 23.300595 14.336305 spread bad",
    "6 8.371528  5.960366 clumped bad",
    "7 16.364583 11.525207 centered_good bad",
    "8 7.062500 11.125915 centered_bad bad")

df <- read.table(text=te, header=T)

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=pattern, y=mean, fill=quality))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), 
            width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]